# How to know if an `com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference` is an Enum?

Tags: java, debugging, jvmti, jdi

How to find out if an `com.sun.jdi.ObjectReference` instance is an enum? I can get the type of the instance with `ObjectReference.type()` which gives a `ClassType` back (if it is a class).

Comment: According to the javadoc there is a `isEnum()` method on `ClassType`. Never tried it myself. Does it work?

Comment: @k5_, OMG, I'm so tired I didn't even see it. I tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `isEnum()` method on `com.sun.jdi.ClassType`